# Scheduler data structures

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, cfs

Does any body know that where CFS scheduling algorithm's data (for example content of suspend or ready queue, task duration, ...) is stored in Linux? (Is there any special file or data structure for this goal?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CFS keeps a different *runqueue* for each processing unit in the system (i.e., it is not a global scheduler, but rather it relies on task migration among the different runqueues). The data structure is **struct cfs_rq** in the [kernel/sched/sched.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched/sched.h) file.

Then, each runqueue internally keeps tasks ordered through a [Red-Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) data structure. The implementation of this data structure is contained in the [include/linux/rbtree.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/rbtree.h) file. It is a generic implementation in the sense that it is not strictly related to scheduling, and thus it can be used by any kernel component that needs to keep data sorted with this kind of data structure.

Within the kernel code, the data structure containing information about a process (or a thread) is **task_struct**, contained inside [include/linux/sched.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/sched.h). This is the main task data structure, used by all scheduling policies (i.e., [SCHED_FAIR, SCHED_FIFO/SCHED_RR, SCHED_DEADLINE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730634/2214693), etc.)

A [good documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt) about how CFS works is contained inside the [Documentation/scheduler](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/scheduler) directory.

Comment: Thank you Claudio. they are quit useful But something which i'm looking for is a specific file or directory or data structure which contains the CFS's runtime data, such as queue. can you give me a clue?

Comment: Check if my new answer answers your question.

Comment: thanks a lot Claudio. it was very good. but a little detailed, i wanna ask you that is it possible that with some trick, see the content of cfs_rq or task_struct at run time? (I think that these are something which may sore in main memory during run time but i ask if there will be a trick).

Comment: If your kernel has been compiled with debugging symbols, then you can inspect data structures at run-time using a debugger lik GDB (read-only) or KGDB. Have a look at http://www.elinux.org/Debugging_The_Linux_Kernel_Using_Gdb