# How to repeat a process ( or to set a period of process) in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, timer, clock

I have a process that does something and needs to be repeated after a period of 1ms. How can I set period of a process on linux ?

I am using linux 3.2.0-4-rt-amd64 (with RT-Preempt patch) on Intel i7 -2600 CPU (total 8 cores) @ 3.40 Ghz.
Basically I have about 6 threads in while loop shown in code and I want threads to be executed at every 1 ms. At the end I want to measure latency of each thread.

So How to set the period 1ms ?

for example in following code, how can I repeat Task1 after every 1ms ?

```
while(1){

   //Task1(having threads)

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you considered using crontab ?

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: use sleep(), see *man 3 sleep* for details.

Comment: @EmilCondrea crontab for a period of 1 ms? Are you serious?

Comment: @arco444: I came to know about clock_nanosleep(), taks1 can sleep after its execution for the remaing time till 1ms reached and then process can be repeated. But I do not want task1 to sleep. Thanks.

Comment: @unwind oups I read fast and I did not see that he specified the period.

Comment: On which precise hardware and on which kernel are you running?

Comment: **Why do you ask**? Why do you exactly need a millisecond delay?? What is your program trying to do? Can't you bear with a larger delay (e.g. a centisecond)?

Comment: Threads may be run in parallel (on different cores of your i7 processors). So executing them every millisecond might not have any sense. **Show more code**

Answer (score 0):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html).

One millisecond is really a small period of time. (Can't you bear with e.g. a ten milliseconds delay?). I'm not sure regular processes on regular Linux on common laptop hardware are able to deal *reliably* with such a small period. Maybe you need [RTLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtlinux) or at least real time scheduling (see [sched_setscheduler(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9374653/841108)) and perhaps a specially configured recent 3.x kernel

You can't be sure that your processing (inside your loop) is smaller than a millisecond.

You should explain what is your application doing, and what happens inside the loop.

You might have some event loop, consider using [ppoll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ppoll.2.html), [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) (see also [timer_getoverrun(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_getoverrun.2.html)...) and/or [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) and [clock_nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html)

(I would try something using `ppoll` and `timerfd_create` but I would accept some millisecond ticks to be skipped)

You should tell us more about your hardware and your kernel. I'm not even sure my desktop i3770K processor, asus P8Z77V motherboard, (3.13.3 `PREEMPT` Linux kernel) is able to *reliably* deal with a single millisecond delay.

(Of course, a plain loop simply calling `clock_nanosleep`, or better yet, using `timerfd_create` with `ppoll`, will *usually* do the job. But that is not *reliable*...)

Comment: The above answer is still relevant for your updated question. And you should still explain why you want a one millisecond period. What exactly is your application doing? What is happening *inside* the loop (in addition of the millisecond wait)?

Answer (score 0):

A call to `usleep(1000)` inside the while loop will do the job, i.e.:

```
while (1) {
    // Task1
    usleep(1000); // 1000 microseconds = 1 millisecond
}
```

**EDIT**

Since `usleep()` is already deprecated in favor of `nanosleep()`, let's use the latter instead:

```
struct timespec timer;
timer.tv_sec = 0;
timer.tv_nsec = 1000000L;

while (1) {
    // Task1
    nanosleep(&timer, NULL);
}
```

Comment: It probably won't be reliable enough. And `usleep` is obsolete and removed from Posix 2008.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You're right about the deprecation, sir. `nanosleep()` should be used instead. About the reliability, I guess it depends on how precise does the author need it to be.