# Performance changes significantly every time I rerun program

Tags: c, performance, hardware

I have a Rasberry PI like hardware which has a basic linux operating system and only one program running called "Main_Prog".

Every time I run a performance test again Main_Prog I get a less than 1% performance fluctuation.  This is perfectly acceptable.

When I kill Main_Prog using the kill command, and re-start Main_Prog, the performance changes up to 8%.  Further performance tests will vary less than 1% around this fluctuation.

---

### Example

So for example if Main_Prog at first ran at **100 calls/sec** and varied between **99-101 calls/sec**.

I then did a "kill" command against Main_Prog and restarted using "./Main_Prog &".  I then run a performance test and now Main_Prog is running **105 calls/sec** with **104-106 calls/sec** fluctuation.  It will continue to run **104-106 calls/sec** until I kill the Main_Prog and start it.

---

Any idea how to prevent fluctuation or what is happening?  Remember, it is VERY consistent. No other programs running on operating system.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly -- you are trying to prevent a program from running faster? ;-)

Comment: haha.  No no.  It would fluctuate by -8% as well.  I do want consistency and getting the best of the fluctuation would be nice as well.

Comment: For performance testing.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what an unnecessary comment. Bravo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your *temporary* fluctuation might be related to the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). I would not bother (the change is *insignificant*). See also http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

You might prefill the page cache, e.g. by running some `wc Main_Prog`  before running `./Main_Prog`

And you probably still do have some other [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) programs & [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) on your Raspberry Pi (check with `top` or `ps auxw`). I guess that `/sbin/init` is still running at pid 1. And probably your shell is running too.

<sup>It is quite unusual to have a Linux system with only one process. To get that, you should replace `/sbin/init` with your program, and I really don't recommend that, especially if you don't know Linux very well.</sup>

Since there are several processes running in your box, and because the kernel [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) is [preempting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) tasks at arbitrary moment, its behavior is not entirely reproducible, and that explains the observed fluctuation.

Read also more about [real-time scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9374653/841108), [setpriority(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpriority.2.html), [sched_setscheduler(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html), [pthread_setschedparam(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html), [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html), [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html)

If you are mostly interested in benchmarking, the sensible way is to repeat the same benchmark several times (e.g. 4 to 15 times) and either take the minimum, or the maximum, or the average.

Comment: Yes you are correct that it is not one process.  It seems there are about 10 - 20 needed processes that I assume the OS needs to be able to run.  I did not replace /sbin/init.  Yes, you are right the % change is very small.  Though, I would like it to be the same results just for consistency.

Comment: @slowmo - just measure how much each call takes and let the threat sleep for the excess time before the next one

Comment: WOW!!  The "wc Main_Prog" actually works!  It is now running at its best fluctuation consistently.  So now I need to make sure I run "wc Main_Prog" every time I want to kill/restart Main_Prog.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that page caching clearing might be a more correct answer!  Doing "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" yielded more consistent results.